# Parsing Text file with irregular column width into Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parsing, text, column-width

I need help in parsing below text into Pandas dataframe columns

```
(11/15/22 2:48:46 PM EST) 14:48:33.671 - 42300146: GWS: 2022-11-15 18:18:33.638 RESTQueue No request to signal.
(11/15/22 11:55:59 AM EST) 11:40:22.750 - 31009225: GWS: 2022-11-15 15:10:22.748  Message Type Received: Slots
(11/8/22 8:03:39 AM EST) 07:32:38.188 - 28624922: Timed out waiting for incoming connections, retry after couple of secs
```

Below is the expected output.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (11/15/22 2:48:46 PM EST) | 14:48:33.671 | 42300146 | GWS: 2022-11-15 18:18:33.638 RESTQueue No request to signal. |
| (11/15/22 11:55:59 AM EST) | 11:40:22.750 | 31009225 | GWS: 2022-11-15 15:10:22.748 Message Type Received: Slots |
| (11/8/22 8:03:39 AM EST) | 07:32:38.188 | 28624922 | Timed out waiting for incoming connections, retry after couple of secs |

Note: The first and fourth column have different width.

I have tried to use read_fwf with specific width but didn't produce the output that I want.
I couldn't use read_csv since there is no delimiter (other than whitespace) between columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression to parse the text ([regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/s9Ari0/1))

```py
text = """\
(11/15/22 2:48:46 PM EST) 14:48:33.671 - 42300146: GWS: 2022-11-15 18:18:33.638 RESTQueue No request to signal.
(11/15/22 11:55:59 AM EST) 11:40:22.750 - 31009225: GWS: 2022-11-15 15:10:22.748  Message Type Received: Slots
(11/8/22 8:03:39 AM EST) 07:32:38.188 - 28624922: Timed out waiting for incoming connections, retry after couple of secs"""

import re
import pandas as pd

pat = re.compile(r"(\(.*?\))\s+(\S+)\s+-\s+(\d+):\s+(.*)")

data = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    m = pat.search(line)
    if m:
        data.append(m.groups())

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     Column 1      Column 2  Column 3                                                                Column 4
0   (11/15/22 2:48:46 PM EST)  14:48:33.671  42300146            GWS: 2022-11-15 18:18:33.638 RESTQueue No request to signal.
1  (11/15/22 11:55:59 AM EST)  11:40:22.750  31009225              GWS: 2022-11-15 15:10:22.748  Message Type Received: Slots
2    (11/8/22 8:03:39 AM EST)  07:32:38.188  28624922  Timed out waiting for incoming connections, retry after couple of secs
```